Interesting Euclidean Geometry problem tricky to prove
Three rays are drawn through a point $X$, forming angles with each other equal to $120°$. A circle of radius $R$ is chosen arbitrarily so that the point $X$ lies inside it. Let $A, B, C$ be the intersection points of the rays with the circle.
Find max $(XA+XB+XC)$.
We all know its $3R$, but tricky to prove it....
[EDIT]
I tried with inequality ,
Let $OX=x$ ($O$ is center of circle)
So , from triangle inequality,
$ R+x>XB $
$ R+x>XA $
$ R+x>XC $
So , $XA+XB+XC<3R+3x$

Do you test us or you need help solving?

Need help solving , im trying with inequalities but no progress

If you extend each segment to the other direction from X and intersect with the circle you could create a different set of inequalities with relation to 2R. Could this help?

This isn't the most elegant way:
Let $x,y,z$ be the distances of $A,B,C$ from $X$. Then the sides of the triangle $ABC$ are given by
$$
a^2 = y^2+z^2+yz,\quad b^2 = z^2+x^2+zx,\quad c^2 = x^2+y^2+xy,
$$
and its circumradius is given by
\begin{align}
R^2 &= \frac{a^2b^2c^2}{2(a^2b^2+b^2c^2+c^2a^2)-(a^4+b^4+c^4)}
\\
&= \frac{(x^2+y^2+xy)(y^2+z^2+yz)(z^2+x^2+zx)}{3(xy+yz+zx)^2}.
\end{align}
Now, we have
\begin{align}
&3(x^2+y^2+xy)(y^2+z^2+yz)(z^2+x^2+zx)
\\
&= (xy+yz+zx)^2(x+y+z)^2 + \color{red}{z^2 (x^2 - y^2)^2 + y^2 (z^2 - x^2)^2 + x^2 (y^2 - z^2)^2}
\\
&\quad + \color{green}{x^2 y^2 [(x - z)^2 + (y - z)^2] + y^2 z^2 [(y - x)^2 + (z - x)^2] + z^2 x^2 [(z - y)^2 + (x - y)^2]}
\\
&\quad + \color{blue}{x^3 y^3 + y^3 z^3 + z^3 x^3 + x^4 y z + y^4 z x + z^4 x y - 6 x^2 y^2 z^2}.
\end{align}
The quantities in red and green are manifestly positive. The quantity in blue is also positive by the AM-GM inequality
\begin{align}
&x^3 y^3 + y^3 z^3 + z^3 x^3 + x^4 y z + y^4 z x + z^4 x y
\\
&\ge 6 (x^3 y^3 \cdot y^3 z^3 \cdot z^3 x^3 \cdot x^4 y z \cdot y^4 z x \cdot z^4 x y)^{1/6} = 6 x^2y^2z^2.
\end{align}
Therefore,
$$
(x^2+y^2+xy)(y^2+z^2+yz)(z^2+x^2+zx) \ge \frac13(xy+yz+zx)^2(x+y+z)^2,
$$
and we conclude that
$$
R \ge \frac13(x+y+z).
$$

Can we solve it using complex bashing,  like origin as center of circle and we have to proof |A-X|+|B-X|+|C-X|<=3R, now using some inequality ?

I don't know immediately

Well-known fact: $X$ is the Fermat point of triangle $ABC$.
For a triangle with angles at most $120^\circ$, this point minimizes $\sum_{P} |PA| + |PB| + |PC|$, where $P$ is any point in the plane (not necessarily within the triangle).
Observation: $ \angle BAC \leq \angle BXC =  120^\circ$, since $X$ is contained in triangle $ABC$.
Corollary: $ABC$ is a triangle with angles at most $120^\circ$. So the Fermat point minimizes the sum of distances the vertex from any point, and in particular the center of the circle. Thus
$$|XA| + |XB| + |XC| \leq |OA| + |OB| + |OC| = 3R.$$
Equality can be achieved when $ X = O$, so $ \max |XA| + |XB| + |XC| = 3R$.
